# Можно ли значение по умолчанию для одного столбца быть другим столбцом?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица `product`. Если в столбце `description` не введено значения, то хотел бы, чтобы оно по умолчанию было равно значению в столбце `product_name`.

То есть, что то подобное:

```
CONSTRAINT def_desc DEFAULT product.product_name FOR description;
```

Но это конечно не работает.

Возможно ли вообще это?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can the default value of one column be another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65370628) от участника [@uckocaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13325358/uckocaman)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65370628

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Значение по умолчанию может быть или литералом, или (в общем случае) детерминированой функцией, то есть, результат которoй не меняется при каждом вызове с теми же параметрами.

Логической проблемой при использовании другого столбца - что должно стать значением при изменении столбца, на который делается ссылка. Если, допустим, так будет работать:

```
create table t (
     x int, y int default x);
    
insert into t (x) values (1);

update t set x = 2;
```

Что теперь ожидается в столбце `y`, значение `1` or `2`?

Если надо, чтобы `y` было `2`, то можно воспользоваться виртуальным столбцом с вычисляемым значением.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370648) от участника [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Нет, значение по-умолчанию для столбца не может быть значением другого столбца.

Можно конечно воспользоваться триггером для присвоения столбцу с `NULL` значения другого столбца, но гораздо проще и лучше будет решение - объявить столбец как `NOT NULL`, и тем самым принудить при вставке задавать значение "по-умолчанию" явно.

Вот так:

```
create table product (name varchar2 (8), description varchar2 (32) not null);

insert into product (name) values ('product1');
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DB"."PRODUCT"."DESCRIPTION")

declare 
    name product.name%type := 'product1';
    description product.description%type;
begin 
    insert into product values (name, coalesce (description, name));
end;
/
select * from product
/
NAME     DESCRIPTION                     
-------- --------------------------------
product1 product1
```

Comment: *но гораздо проще и лучше будет решение - объявить столбец как NOT NULL, и тем самым принудить при вставке задавать значение "по-умолчанию" явно.* Решение, хорошее на этапе разработки, но совершенно неприменимое на этапе корректировки введённого в эксплуатацию приложения. Триггер как раз в этом смысле универсален - и применим к рабочему приложению, и позволяет "заткнуть дырку" во время разработки, если до окончательного решения не дошли руки (или оно идеологически ещё не сформировалось).